# My Designer Attributes is not show anything on Android studio

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w02c0.png)  See photo link, as I am new. My designer attributes on Android studio is completely blank. I cannot find a similar bug, and I am so wet behind the ears on app development that I have no idea where to start to fix it, besides uninstalling and reinstalling - which I have already done. This image shows the blank designer attributes category. TIA

Comment: external link to resources ...........................................

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken this does not work for classes and non-xml files, open a layout file (activity_main.xml) and then check the designer attributes tab for any changes